# reading .key file android

Tags: android, file

I have problem when i try to read a .key file. This file is created by a normal java (J2SE) and i read it from android application. When i read this file from android it gives me nothing and i have done some debugging and i noticed that it can't read the file. Also i have checked if i can read the file (using `file.canRead())` and it appears that i can't. Notice that i created normal java application (J2SE) with the same code and it worked successfully.

The code I have used is this:

```
    public KeyPair LoadKeyPair(String algorithm, String publicFileName, String privateFileName) {
    // Read Public Key.
    PublicKey publicKey = null;
    PrivateKey privateKey = null;
    try {
    File filePublicKey = new File(publicFileName);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(publicFileName); // The program stops here
    byte[] encodedPublicKey = new byte[(int) filePublicKey.length()];
    fis.read(encodedPublicKey);
    fis.close();

// Read Private Key.
File filePrivateKey = new File(privateFileName);
fis = new FileInputStream(privateFileName);
byte[] encodedPrivateKey = new byte[(int) filePrivateKey.length()];
fis.read(encodedPrivateKey);
fis.close();

// Generate KeyPair.
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(
encodedPublicKey);
publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);

PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(
encodedPrivateKey);
privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
return new KeyPair(publicKey, privateKey);
}
```

Comment: where are you reading the file from? SDcard?

Comment: it is in the same directory of android app

Answer (score 0):

Is a .key file just like a .pem file?

If so, I just do something like this, because PemReader is in BouncyCastleProvider, and THAT is a mess! Too much code for too few things that I want to use

```
if(mKey==null){
        BufferedReader pubFile = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mCtx.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.public.pem)));
        try {
            String line = new String();
            StringBuilder key = new StringBuilder();
            while((line = pubFile.readLine())!= null){
                if(!line.contains("----")){
                    key.append(line);
                }
            }
            mKey = key.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                pubFile.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I have my public.pem in the res/raw/ folder within my application. Of course, I dont have a .pem with the private key in it. I sign with my public key and verify that the info was signed with a public key made from the private key I keep on my server.

Hope that answers your question and is clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add in the Manifest the following line?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Where is android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE documentd.  I could not find it in Manifets.permission.

Comment: You need to add this line in the Manifest if it doesn't exist.

Comment: This permission does not exist (see all the existing ones here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html ).
However, note that READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE exists since API 16.